# Move shape around using c# and for loops

Tags: c#, for-loop, graphics

I am very new to this style of programming, so I am experimenting with it.

I need to get the square to move left and right instead of up and down, how would I alter the code to do this?

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace BouncingBall
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int square;
        int rect;
        int ball;
        Thread t;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            t = new Thread(Run);
            t.Start();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;

            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 0, ball, 20, 20);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.BurlyWood, 120, rect, 50, 50);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, 300, square, 10, 60);    
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Abort();
            t.Join();
        }

        private void Run() {
            int dy = 1;
            int ux = 1;
            int lr = 1;
            ball = 0;
            square = 150;
            rect = 95;

            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 140; i++)
                {
                    ball += dy;
                    Invalidate();
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                dy = -dy;

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    square -= ux;
                    Invalidate();
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                ux  = -ux;

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    rect -= lr;
                    Invalidate();
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }

                lr = -lr;     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To solicit a good answer, you'll probably need to describe what you've tried to do, and what incorrect behavior is exhibited, exceptions, etc. Folks are unlikely to take your code sample, run it, and diagnose. The code sample is a great start though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position that your square moves is defined by the second and third parameters of the [FillRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6ksfcek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function.

The second parameter is the horizontal position, and the third parameter is the vertical position.

To get your square to move horizontally, you have to change the value of the second parameter(that is the horizontal position)

change

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, 300, square, 10, 60);
```

to

```
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, square, 300, 10, 60);
```